How to Use Google Cloud Identity/Workspace as an OIDC Identity Provider for Custom third party Applications?
I’m trying to use Google Cloud Identity as an OIDC (OpenID Connect) identity provider to integrate third-party applications (service providers) that support OIDC for authentication. However, I’m encountering difficulties because the documentation predominantly focuses on SAML, with only sparse references to OIDC.
I tried looking at the documentation and here’s what I’ve found so far:

Most guides and references (e.g., Ref-1, Ref-2) focus on SAML configuration.
OIDC is mentioned occasionally (Ref), but there’s no clear guide for integrating custom applications using OIDC.
Additionally, I came across a  similar post (Ref) in the past, but it seems the question wasn’t fully addressed.

My specific requirements:

I need to integrate a custom app, not one of the preconfigured apps available in the catalog, with GOOGLE CLOUD IDENTITY as the identity provider.
I’m aware of the Google Identity Platform (CIAM), but that’s NOT what I want to use. My goal is to achieve this using only Google Cloud Identity.

Has anyone successfully configured Google Cloud Identity as an IDP for custom apps using OIDC? If so, could you share the steps or point me to relevant documentation?

The Google Workspace OpenID Connect implementation is lacking, mostly because it does not support any custom claims or group claims. It is therefor recommended to use Google Workspace with SAML 2.0 and use a bridge to convert to OpenID Connect for your application.
You can for example connect FoxIDs to Google Workspace with SAML 2.0 and use it at a bridge between SAML 2.0 and OpenID Connect.
